# How to iterate array of JSON object through AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object, from which I want to get the output like this and **console.log** into browser.

> FROM: Frontier WHSE, TO: ENTEC POLYMERS

JSON object to traverse:

```
 {
    "loadStops": [{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "FROM",
        "stop": {
            "companyId": 148,
            "companyCode": "FWS",
            "legalName": "Frontier WHSE"
        }
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "TO",
        "stop": {
            "companyId": 151,
            "companyCode": "ENP",
            "legalName": "ENTEC POLYMERS"
        }
    }]
}
```

**I tried this** but didn't work exactly:

```
var from = "";
var to = "";
var summary = "";

angular.forEach( object, function() {

    if( key == "type" && value == "FROM" ) {
        from +=value;
    }

    if( key == "type" && value == "TO" ) {
        to+=value;
    }

});

summary += from + to;
```

Comment: are you sure that you want an array of objects (with "FROM" and "TO")? you can try to format it if you know the order in which they come in (by index): `console.log(\`FROM: ${json.loadStops[0].stop.legalName} WHSE, TO: ${json.loadStops[1].stop.legalName}\`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.data = 
 {
"loadStops": [{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "FROM",
    "stop": {
        "companyId": 148,
        "companyCode": "FWS",
        "legalName": "Frontier WHSE"
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "TO",
    "stop": {
        "companyId": 151,
        "companyCode": "ENP",
        "legalName": "ENTEC POLYMERS"
    }
}]};
var summary = "";
$scope.print = function(){
angular.forEach($scope.data.loadStops,function(key,value){
    if(key.type == "FROM"){
       summary = "FROM :" + key.stop.legalName;
    }
    if(key.type == "TO"){
      summary += " TO :" + key.stop.legalName;
    }
   
});
return summary;
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <h1>{{print()}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `summary = "FROM ...` should have `+=`

Comment: what? edit _your_ code? (I only mentioned it because if you have more that once case of `"FROM"` types, you will overwrite `summary`)